# Change javascript show/hidden text function

Tags: javascript

It works... but i want to change the default to hidden.
Click first time to show the hidden text

```
<script>
function displayRow(itemID){
    if ((document.getElementById(itemID).style.display == 'block')) {
        document.getElementById(itemID).style.display = 'display';
    } else { 
        document.getElementById(itemID).style.display = 'display'; 
    }
}
</script>

<button onclick="displayRow('1')">Show/Hidden text</button>
```

Comment: You can just add `style="display: hidden;"` to your element, or a class which has that trait by default

Comment: `document.getElementById(itemID).style.display = 'display';` 
This doesn't do anything, i.e. `display: display` is not valid CSS.

`document.getElementById(itemID).style.display = 'none';`  would be better (or use visibility or opacity instead)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function displayRow(itemID){
    if ((document.getElementById(itemID).style.display == 'none')) {
        document.getElementById(itemID).style.display = 'block';
    } else { 
        document.getElementById(itemID).style.display = 'none'; 
    }
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr style="display:none" id="1">
<td>Test</td>
</tr>
</table>
<button onclick="displayRow('1')">Show/Hidden text</button>
```

Use "none" instead "hidden", and put style="display: none" to the element which want to hide by default

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Simply set your display to hidden by default

```
<button style='display: hidden;' onclick="displayRow('<? echo $element ?>')" class='no-print'>Show/Hidden text</button>
```

and the js

```
function displayRow(itemID){
    var el = document.getElementById(itemID);
    if ((el.style.display == 'hidden')) {
        el.style.display = 'block';
    } else { 
        el.style.display = 'hidden'; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function displayRow(itemID){
  if (document.getElementById(itemID).style.display == 'block') {
    document.getElementById(itemID).style.display = 'none';
  } else { 
    document.getElementById(itemID).style.display = 'block'; 
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. In addition to the code you've provided, please consider giving a summary as to why and how this solves the issue.